# UrlFilenameViewController does not return View (Spring-MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping

According to Spring framework API

UrlFilenameViewController's purpose is:

> Transforms the virtual path of a URL into a view name and returns that view

If i request for /info.xhtml, its logical view name is info

See [UrlFilenameViewController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/UrlFilenameViewController.html) documentation

Both web.xml and controller is mapped according to

```
/WEB-INF/web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>smac</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

/WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/output/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
</beans>
```

My smac app deploys fine.

So, if i request for http://127.0.0.1:8080/smac/info.xhtml, Spring-MVC should return /WEB-INF/output/info.jsp. But i have seen in console the following:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/smac/info.xhtml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'controller'

Could anyone help me ?

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a [HandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping). Default one is `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` which will only do what you want if you bind your controller bean under the name matching your URI. You probably want the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` instead:

```
<bean name="myController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /**/*.xhtml=myController
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```